# Converting a string containing whitespace-delimited numbers to a list of numbers

Tags: string-manipulation

Suppose I have a string `str` that contains only whitespace-delimited real numbers:

```
str = " 0\t1.46604\t1.44829\t12.0546\t1.57075\t1.64044\t12.0489\t1.58142";
```

I would like to convert `str` to a list of real numbers.  One way to accomplish this is to split the string using `StringSplit` and then `Map` the function `ToExpression` across the resulting list:

```
Map[ToExpression, StringSplit[str]]
```

which gives the correct output:

> {0, 1.46604, 1.44829, 12.0546, 1.57075, 1.64044, 12.0489, 1.58142}

But, is there a cleaner or more efficient way to do this?  I will be converting about 100,000 strings `str` -- each of which are approximately the same length as the example `str` above -- which will be read as records from a text file (i.e., using `OpenRead` and `Read`), so it would be nice if the method is relatively efficient.  Thank you for your time!

Comment: Although, I'm not sure why, `ToExpression["{" <> StringReplace[str, "\t" -> ", "] <> "}"]` seems to be a tad faster than both `StringSplit` and `StringToDouble` methods.

Comment: @kale probably because you are only searching for `/t`, and not for the other possible string separators _Whitespace is taken to include spaces, tabs and newlines._

Comment: @kale, not clearly faster than `StringToDouble` in my test. Also probably because there's only one string to expression conversion there

Comment: @Rojo, Yeah, we're not talking much, but consistently a little faster on my machine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
str = " 0\t1.46604\t1.44829\t12.0546\t1.57075\t1.64044\t12.0489\t1.58142";
ToExpression[StringSplit[str, Whitespace]]

(* {0, 1.46604, 1.44829, 12.0546, 1.57075, 1.64044, 12.0489, 1.58142} *)
```

Comment: Nice one +1, I didn't realise `ToExpression` was listable

Answer (score 10):

You could also try

```
Internal`StringToDouble /@ StringSplit[str]
```

But I don't think your speed  limitation will be in the conversion but in the repeated reading of the records. Just guessing.

If you had some long string perhaps you could also try `Flatten@ImportString[str, "Table"]`

As of [12.3](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/246449/is-internalstringtodouble-broken-in-12-3), the internal function name is `` Internal`StringToMReal ``

Comment: Careful with this `Internal\`StringToDouble`. I would always use `StringTrim` before it. I just found that `Internal\`StringToDouble["-1"]` returns -1.0 while `Internal\`StringToDouble[" -1"]`, with an extra leading space,   returns positive 1.0.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, since your data is separated by tabs:

```
data = "0\t1.46604\t1.44829\t12.0546\t1.57075\t1.64044\t12.0489\t1.58142";
ImportString[data, "TSV"] // First
   {0, 1.46604, 1.44829, 12.0546, 1.57075, 1.64044, 12.0489, 1.58142}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Using ReadList:**

```
str = " 0\t1.46604\t1.44829\t12.0546\t1.57075\t1.64044\t12.0489\t1.58142";
ReadList[StringToStream[str], Number]

 (*{0, 1.46604, 1.44829, 12.0546, 1.57075, 1.64044, 12.0489, 1.58142}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using `StringCases`**:

```
str = " 0\t1.46604\t1.44829\t12.0546\t1.57075\t1.64044\t12.0489\t\
1.58142";
StringCases[str, NumberString] // ToExpression
```

> {0, 1.46604, 1.44829, 12.0546, 1.57075, 1.64044, 12.0489, 1.58142}