# How do I extract a number from a string?

Tags: string-manipulation

I want to extract the number from an alphanumeric string. This is what I tried:

```
StringTake["thiru3", {6, 6}]
```

The result I got is `3`, but it is still a `String`, which I determined by evaluating:

```
NumberQ[StringTake["thiru3", {6, 6}]]
```

which returns `False`.

Comment: Related or possible duplicate: [How do you convert a string containing a number in C scientific notation to a Mathematica number?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1737/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. I don't think it's a duplicate. This is about extracting a simple integer, not about a real an encoded in a string.

Answer (score 19):

```
 StringCases["thiru3", x : NumberString :> ToExpression[x]]
 (* {3} *)
 First[%]
 (* 3 *)
 {NumberQ[%], Head[%]}
 (* {True, Integer} *)
```

Comment: As noted by ssch in Chris's answer, `FromDigits[]` might be better to use than `ToExpression[]`.

Comment: `NumberString` will match real number strings and `FromDigits` will balk; `ToExpression` will convert them.  I would say `NumberString` & `ToExpression` for real numbers, or, for integers only, `DigitCharacter..` and `FromDigits`.  You won't get messages in either case, as in ssch's comment, because `FromDigits` is called only when there is a match.

Answer (score 12):

Try to use ToExpression, like this

```
ToExpression[StringTake["thiru3", {6, 6}]]
```

If you check it with Head[%] it confirms that it is an Integer

Answer (score 11):

Alternatively, and for multiple numbers:-

```
Map[FromDigits, Select[Characters["thiru37"], DigitQ]]
```

> {3, 7}

**Latterly**

```
ToExpression@StringCases["thiru37", DigitCharacter]
```

> {3, 7}

Comment: I think `FromDigits` is the best way since you will immediatly get a message printed in case it didn't work, that you can `Check` for if need be

Answer (score 9):

Here is one compact option

```
Internal`StringToDouble@"thiru3"
```

> 3.

Comment: Nice - where the heck did you get that from?

Comment: Ahh.. I was looking for a faster way to [make conversions from string to numbers](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19628/2266), and found it [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10137/converting-a-string-containing-whitespace-delimited-numbers-to-a-list-of-numbers/10138#10138)

Answer (score 3):

Like `NumberString`, `DigitCharacter` can be used to find numbers in a string. Use relative positioning in the string (like `EndOfString`) to localize your digits and ignore other numbers possibly appearing at other positions:

```
First@StringCases["0thi12ru3", (n:DigitCharacter~~EndOfString) :> ToExpression@n]

(* ==> 3 *)
```

This searches for exactly one number character right before the end of string. If the terminal number could have more than one digits, use `DigitCharacter..` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Consider:

```
str = "thiru37aa2er45"
```

then

```
StringCases[str, DigitCharacter ..]
```

yields:

```
{"37", "2", "45"}

StringCases[str, DigitCharacter .]
```

yields:

```
{"3", "7", "2", "4", "5"}
```

They can be converted to expressions using `ToExpression`

Comment: `StringCases["thiru37aa2er45", x : DigitCharacter .. :> FromDigits[x]]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thank you...all in one step

Answer (score 2):

```
s = "thiru3";
r = First@StringCases[s, RegularExpression["\\d+"]];
Needs["JLink`"];
InstallJava[];
LoadJavaClass["java.lang.Integer"];
z = Integer`parseInt[r]
Head[z]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: bbbut... why not `ToExpression@r`?

Comment: @rm-rf The sarcasm character doesn't display in your browser I guess.

Comment: wish I could upvote twice. what an economical solution

Answer (score 1):

Can be so

```
ToExpression[StringCases["thiru3", DigitCharacter ..]][[1]]
```

or

```
ToExpression[
  StringCases["thiru3", "thiru" ~~ (x : DigitCharacter ..) -> x]][[1]]
```

or

```
ToExpression[StringCases["thiru3", RegularExpression["\\d+"]][[1]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Read[StringToStream[StringTake["thiru3", {6, 6}]]]
```