# Faster way to convert real strings into numbers

Tags: string-manipulation, code-request

Working with big files, I have to convert some numbers that are in string format into real MMA numbers. I know that I can use `ToExpression` but it's slow when compared to another forms.

For instance, for Integer case we can compare:

```
dataInt = ToString /@ RandomInteger[1000, {10^5}];
d1 = FromDigits /@ dataInt; // AbsoluteTiming
d2 = ToExpression /@ dataInt; // AbsoluteTiming

{0.050298, Null}
{0.475669, Null}
```

It's almost 10 times faster to use `FromDigits`. The question is, how can I make a equivalent for Real cases? Like:

```
dataReal = ToString /@ RandomReal[1000, {10^5}];
d1 = someFunction/@dataReal;//AbsoluteTiming
d2 = ToExpression/@dataReal;//AbsoluteTiming
```

I haven't found some Mathematica function to `someFunction`. I miss one way to force `ToExpression` to interpret the string in some specific way.

Comment: This begs the question as to why you aren't just reading the numbers as ... numbers, ReadList[] style.

Comment: I have numbers with comma as separator like "23,23", so I have to use StringReplace and then convert into number.

Comment: Can you read as import as "Table"?

Comment: `Import` is slow, I use `ReadList` that hasn't this option.

Answer (score 9):

I found [in this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10138/2266) the function `` Internal`StringToDouble `` that does exactly what I was looking for:

```
dataReal = ToString /@ RandomReal[1000, {10^5}];
d1 = Internal`StringToDouble /@ dataReal; // AbsoluteTiming
d2 = ToExpression /@ dataReal; // AbsoluteTiming
d1 == d2
{0.045391, Null}
{0.544008, Null}
True
```

As you can see, 10x faster then `ToExpression`.

As of [12.3](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/246449/is-internalstringtodouble-broken-in-12-3), the Internal function is `` Internal`StringToMReal ``

Answer (score 1):

Well yours is better and faster but I'll post this anyways. This is the best I can do for the moment. For 10^6 values its about 15% faster then ToExpression:

```
First@ImportString[
    StringReplace[StringDrop[StringDrop[ToString[dataReal], 1], -1], 
     "," -> ""], "Table"]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

Comment: tks @S0rce! I haven't sow `ImportString`, it has some `Real` options.