# StringCases using RegularExpression fails when there is missing data

Tags: pattern-matching, regular-expressions

I got some text scraps with this *structure*

```
"Focal Plane: 198'  Active Aid to Navigation: Yes  *Latitude: 35.250 N  *Longitude: -75.529 W"
```

But some of them lack of parts like this

```
"Focal Plane: 198'  Active Aid to Navigation: Yes  *Longitude: -75.529 W"
```

Using regular expression matching, I want to extract all the info available, included getting a tag "NotAvailable" for missing data.,

I wrote this code, but it can't tell when a pattern does not match -- should the pattern in the middle not match, my code just skips it and goes on to the next pattern:

```
ptrFocal = "(?<=\\Focal Plane: )(.*?)(?=\\')";
ptrLat = "(?<=\\*Latitude: )(.*?)(?=[a-zA-Z])";
ptrLon = "(?<=\\*Longitude: )(.*?)(?=[a-zA-Z])";

r = 
  StringTrim /@ StringCases[text, 
    RegularExpression[ptrFocal <> "|" <> ptrLat <> "|" <> ptrLon]
  ];
```

I would want some pointers on how to do this.

**EDIT:**

The expected transformation of the example data I gave above is

> ```
> {198, 32.250, -75.529}
> {198, "NotAvailable", -75.529}
> ```

Comment: What would be the desired result for each case? Is regex the only acceptable solution?

Comment: I would "prefer" regex for the patterns, because I already know a little about it :)

Comment: So you are not interested in `W, N, S E`?

Comment: @MHero: You can use `StringPattern\`PatternConvert[XXX] // InputForm` where XXX is the *Mathematica* string pattern to see the regex it gets converted to, just FYI. Might give you some ideas on how to build your own if regex is mandatory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
str1 = "Focal Plane: 198' Active Aid to Navigation: Yes *Latitude: \
35.250 N *Longitude: -75.529 W";

str2 = "Focal Plane: 198.12' Active Aid to Navigation: Yes \
*Longitude: -75.529 W"
```

With string patterns because I do not use regex :)

```
record[string_] := Map[
   StringCases[string, # ~~ x : NumberString :> x] /. {} -> "NotAvailable" &,
   {"Focal Plane: ", "Latitude: ", "Longitude: "}] // Flatten

record@str1

record@str2
```

> ```
> {"198", "35.250", "-75.529"}
> {"198.12", "NotAvailable", "-75.529"}
> ```

You can add `ToExpression /@ StringCases[...` if you need numbers not strings.

Answer (score 2):

A variation of Kuba's method, using a single `StringCases` pass with post processing:

```
str2 = "Focal Plane: 198.12' Active Aid to Navigation: Yes *Longitude: -75.529 W"

fields = {"Focal Plane: ", "Latitude: ", "Longitude: "};

StringCases[str2, a : fields ~~ x : NumberString :> (a -> ToExpression[x])]
fields /. % /. _String :> "NotAvailable"
```

> ```
> "Focal Plane: 198.12' Active Aid to Navigation: Yes *Longitude: -75.529 W"
>
> {"Focal Plane: " -> 198.12, "Longitude: " -> -75.529}
>
> {198.12, "NotAvailable", -75.529}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

As requested, here is one approach using pure `RegularExpression`.

Another difference is the use of `` Internal`StringToDouble `` that is faster then ToExpression (velocity test [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19631/2266)).

```
getFields[str_String]:=Module[{fields,r},
    fields = {"Focal Plane: ", "Latitude: ", "Longitude: "};    
    r=Map[StringCases[str,RegularExpression[#<>"((\\+|-)?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)"]:>Internal`StringToDouble@"$1"]&,fields];
    r=Flatten[r/.{}-> Missing]
]

str1 = "Focal Plane: 198.23'  Active Aid to Navigation: Yes   *Longitude: -75.529 W";
str2 = "Focal Plane: 198.23'  Active Aid to Navigation: Yes  *Latitude: 35.250 N  *Longitude: -75.529 W";

getFields@str1
getFields@str2
```

> {198.23, Missing, -75.529}
>
> {198.23, 35.25`, -75.529}

Comment: Thanks for reminding StringToDouble +1ed ofc. :)