# Does Dataset round?

Tags: bugs, dataset

I'm importing the following Excel file:

[image: Excel file]

My code and its results are:

```
fileTemp = Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "problem.xlsx", {"Sheets", "s1"}];
assoc = AssociationThread[fileTemp[[1]] -> #] & /@ fileTemp[[2 ;;]]
ds = Dataset[assoc]
ds1 = ds[GroupBy[Key["BusinessID"]], Total, "value2"]
```

[image: output1]

It seems to be rounding to the nearest 100.

Applying eldo's workaround I get:

```
fileTemp = Partition[(Flatten[
Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "problem.xlsx", {"Sheets", "s1"}], 1]
/. x_Real :> Round[x]), 5];
assoc = AssociationThread[fileTemp[[1]] -> #] & /@ fileTemp[[2 ;;]]
ds = Dataset[assoc]
ds1 = ds[GroupBy[Key["BusinessID"]], Total, "value2"]
```

[image: output2]

The Excel file should be findable at:
[sample excel file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/so0r3z4spsifgal/problem.xlsx)

Comment: Could you give a sample xlsx file? In case people want to try but don't have an MS Office.

Comment: @Silvia I don't know exactly how to give anyone a test file.  I just installed DropBox, but have never used it before.  Is that the best way?  Any hints?

Comment: It seems you have got your answer:) FWIW I have reproduced the bug with `Dataset[{<|"a" -> 380160.|>}]`, so do you agree we can rephrase the question to excluding the Excel part?

Comment: @Silvia Gee I just figured out how to use DropBox.  But, yes that will simplify things.  Will you do the edit or should I?  I may also have to edit my question, because in my "real" case, I don't know if the problem is limited to a display problem.  I'm using GroupBy and Totaling, and getting rounded totals.  I need to look at my original code and see if the dataset with the totals contains the rounded numbers or is just displaying the rounded numbers.

Comment: As it's your post, if you feel like to edit, it will be more accurate than I editing. Regarding to your worry, I suggest having a look at what the developer of `Dataset` said under [the linked dup-question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55101/dataset-and-string-conversion-using-internalstringtodouble#comment158465_55105).

Comment: @Slivia eldo's workaround seems to solve downstream problems as well.  I'll edit my question by showing the summation I want to do and how eldo's workaround helps.  I'll also post a link to the xlsx file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my opinion it's a bug.

I input your data in Excel without the comma separator, execute the steps as per your question  and get the same wrong result.

A possible workaround:

```
fileTemp = Flatten[Import["C:\\...\\problem.xlsx"], 1] /. x_Real :> Round[x]

assoc = AssociationThread[fileTemp[[1]] -> #] & /@ fileTemp[[2 ;;]]

Dataset[assoc]
```

[image]

Comment: Your workaround works, but I had to wrap it in a Partition[...,5].  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 11):

It appears to be rounding only in the visual representation, but internally it stores the exact number. So e,g. doing:

```
ds[1, "value2"]
```

We get

> 387750.

Which is the number from the excel sheet.

Comment: That's pretty misleading though, I'd still call it a bug.  It is possible that it simply rounds to 4 digits, regardless of how many digits are to the left of the decimal point and how many to the right.  It might make sense to round `2.34567 * 10^6` to `2.346 * 10^6`, but it makes no sense to round `2345670` to `2346000` for display purposes.

Comment: If you agree that it's a bug, go ahead and add the tag.

Comment: @Szabolcs, I mean that internally, the exact number is still available.

Comment: Yes, that's a very useful observation, you already got my +1 for it.  I meant that I'd say it's a formatting/display bug.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks. As per the display, I agree it's probably a bug.