# read data from file having different format numbers

Tags: import, csv-format

I'm trying to process my bank's data, which is always formed by lines with 5 fields separated by semicolons.
Until recently, it used to write the numbers in the "1234,56" format, and I processed them by

```
Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "cc.wri", "Table", 
  "NumberPoint" -> ",", "FieldSeparators" -> {";"}]
```

Recently the bank started using the "1,234.56" format, and since I prefer to use a single file containing all my transactions history, I am wondering if it is possible to read from a file both type of number formats.

I tried using `ToExpression[]`, but without success, and it seems that `NumberPoint` doesnt allow for multiple choices

-> fake cc.wri file: https://pastebin.com/MviN6SBC

---

**update**: I checked that this works, but still dont know if it's the best way to do it:

```
a=Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "cc.wri", "Table", 
      "NumberPoint" -> ",", "FieldSeparators" -> {";"}]
a4 = 
 Map[If[NumberQ[#], #, Internal`StringToDouble[#]] &, 
  a\[Transpose][[4]]]
```

(``` Internal``StringToDouble ``` idea from [Faster way to convert real strings into numbers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19628/faster-way-to-convert-real-strings-into-numbers))

Comment: Is it guaranteed that a file won't have a mix of numbers in both formats?

Comment: No - maybe I didnt explain me well - the file will use the first format until a given line, then switch to the second format from then on

Comment: "until a given line" - would you happen to know how to detect that line? It's hard to discuss possible solutions since you didn't furnish a sample file.

Comment: I added a simple fake file - in any case I wonder if it is possible to have both number formats detected in general, wherever they appear in the file

Answer (score 1):

You might `Import` the whole file as text, do a string replacement like this,

```
StringReplace["1,234.56  1.234,56" ,
  d : ((DigitCharacter | "." | "," ) ..) ~~ ("." | ",") ~~
   c : (DigitCharacter ~~ DigitCharacter) ~~ (EndOfString | 
     Except[DigitCharacter]) :>
  StringReplace[d, {"." -> "", "," -> ""}] <> "." <> c]
```

> 1234.56 1234.56

then `ImportString` the result..