# Is Internal`StringToDouble broken in 12.3?

Tags: string-manipulation, undocumented, numerical-value, compatibility, version-12.3

I believe Internal`StringToDouble was the only way to fast convert string into numbers. Now in V12.3 it was removed:

```
Internal`StringToDouble["1"]
```

> Internal`StringToDouble["1"]

As long as it's broken other options than (the slow) `ToExpression`?

**UPDATED**

Check the accepted answer. There are new functions to do that in V12.3

Comment: Does `Internal\`StringToMReal` do it for you?

Comment: @CarlLange literally just found that (from ``XMPTools`Helpers`Private`stringToReal``). BTW it looks like ``Internal`StringToDouble`` and its counterpart still exist but have had their defs. removed per ``System`Private`HasAnyCodesQ``

Comment: In v12.3 there also appears to be a problem with `Internal\`DoubleToString`

Comment: @CarlLange tks. I believe It can help for now.

Comment: @BobHanlon that's now `MRealToString`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`StringToDouble` was renamed `StringToMReal` as part of code cleanup and the addition of several friends:

```
 ?Internal`StringTo*
 (*Internal`StringToBoolean   Internal`StringToMInteger
   Internal`StringToMReal     Internal`StringToMRational*)
```

It should be as fast, but now in failure cases it returns a proper `Failure` object instead of some bizarro-`$Failed[_String]`. The error checking could be tighter (the new functions are more discriminating), but at least for now it will just truncate when it encounters invalid characters like the old `StringToDouble`.  Note that the `M` in the names is for "Machine".
There shouldn't be an `` Internal`StringToDouble ``, and I don't see it in a clean, standalone kernel.  So perhaps some paclet that is multi-version is referencing and creating it.

Comment: Curiously, ``Internal`StringToDouble`` shows up on wolfram cloud, but does not work.

Comment: What about Internal`DoubleToString? It is still here but lost its definition and stays unevaluated. Bug?

Comment: @Philipp that's now `MRealToString`

Comment: @b3m2a1: Thank you very much. Now I feel stupid because I was looking for RealToString and similar.

Comment: @Itai Seggev: Evaluating Internal\`MRealToString in a clean kernel creates Internal`StringToDouble again which seems wrong.

Comment: The Google Calendar interface uses Internal`StringToDouble for TimeZone specifications, returning things like DateObject["1954-12-03T22:55:00", TimeZone -> Internal`StringToDouble["+01"]] Obviously this was not updated for V12.3. All my applications are broken. Is there a fix?

Comment: As a workaround until this is fixed, you could wrap your code in a `Block` like: ``Block[{Internal`StringToDouble = Internal`StringToMReal}, ServiceExecute[...]]`` - or just make the definition globally: ``Internal`StringToDouble = Internal`StringToMReal``