# How to express number in exponential decimal such as 1e2=100?

Tags: syntax, customization, number-representation, matlab, custom-notation

I am using MATLAB for a long time, and usually I express the number as exponential decimal such as

```
x = 1e2; % x=100
```

However, if I write this form in mathematica, it regards the e between 1 and 2 as a symbol (variable).

Do you guys know any expression using alphabet e for that, or should I change the form into using 10 such as

```
x=10^2;
```

Comment: I do not know of an equivalent to `1e2` except, perhaps, `1*^2`.

Comment: Use: `*^` In the documentation it's mentioned briefly in passing in ref/NumberMarks - also mentioned in tutorial/Numbers

Comment: @bbgodfrey, the expression 1e2 is general form in MATLAB. For example, 3e2 indicates 3 x 10^2. Similarly, 3.2e1 is 3.2 x 10^1 = 32.

Comment: @flinty, thanks for your answer. That helps :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the best thing to do is to get used to the convention of *Mathematica* i.e. using `10^2` or `1*^2`. Anyway, if you insist, one possibility is to make use of free form input by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>:

[image]

But to use free form input it's necessary to connect to the Internet and the interpretation may not always be correct, so a more robust solution is to define our own function:

```
SetAttributes[eScientificNumber, HoldAll];
With[{toreal = 
    If[$VersionNumber >= 12.3, Internal`StringToMReal, Internal`StringToDouble]}, 
  eScientificNumber[n_] := toreal@ToString@Unevaluated@n];

eScientificNumber /: MakeBoxes[eScientificNumber[n_], StandardForm] := 
 TemplateBox[{MakeBoxes@n}, "eScientificNumber", DisplayFunction -> (FrameBox@# &)]
```

The `MakeBoxes[…]` rule isn't necessary, it's just for the sake of aesthetic. The function name `eScientificNumber` is a bit too long to input repeatedly, so let's make use of input aliase and palette:

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, "InputAliases"] = 
  Append[DeleteCases[CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, "InputAliases"], "esn" -> _], 
   "esn" -> MakeBoxes@eScientificNumber[\[SelectionPlaceholder]]];

CreatePalette[PasteButton@Defer@eScientificNumber[\[SelectionPlaceholder]], 
 WindowMargins -> Automatic]
```

You can even add your own keyboard shortcut as shown in e.g. [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5212/1871) but I'd like to stop here.

Now you can input `100` with `1e2` in following manners:

[image]

To understand the answer, you may want to read:

[Preventing Superscript from being interpreted as Power when using Ctrl+^ shortcut?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33672/1871)

[Is Internal`StringToDouble broken in 12.3?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/246449/1871)

[Make a custom object look like MatrixForm of a matrix?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/159337/1871)

Comment: Thanks! It really helps! :D The notations are quite different from MATLAB, but I am getting used to it.